# Join (sum) two adjacent elements of an array into one element until its size is K and GCD of new elements is maximum possible

Tags: algorithm, greatest-common-divisor

I'm having a problem to solve this one. The task is to make a program that will for a given array of N numbers ( N <= 10^5 ), print a new array that's made by joining any two adjacent elements into their sum, (the sum is replacing these two adjacent elements and the size of the array is smaller by 1), until array's size is K. I need to print a solution where GCD of new elements is maximized. (and also print GCD after printing the array).

Note: Sum of all elements in the given array is not higher than 10^6.

I've realized that I could use prefix sum somehow because the sum of all elements isn't higher than 10^6, but that didn't help me that much.

What is an optimal solution to this problem?

Comment: What have you tried? did it work? why?

Comment: I can't code something I don't have a good idea for. There's always an unoptimal solution that exceeds the time limit, but I need the optimal one.

Comment: Did you try the naiive solution? calculate all possible K-size arrays, for each K-array calculate GCD, calculate max GCD and print the K-array with max GCD ?

Comment: If I understand it correctly, then solution is simple: calculate sums for all adjacent elements into new array, then calculate GCD for all elements in this array, then find maximum and join recalculating only affected GCDs, repeat until K is reached.

Comment: If `S` is the sum of all elements in the given array, then the GCD that you seek must be a divisor of `S` that's less than or equal to `S/K`. So I'd start by computing `S` and then finding its divisors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your GCD will be a divisor of the sum of all elements in the array. Your sum is not greater then 10^6, so the number of divisors is not greater than 240, so you can just check all of this GCDs, and it will be fast enough. You can check if asked gcd is possible in linear time: just go through array while the current sum is not the divisor of wanted gcd. When it is just set the current sum to 0. If you have found at least k blocks, it is possible to get current gcd (you can join any 2 blocks, and gcd will be the same).